# Java "NoClassDefError" while running the program on Linux

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have a Java program that imports some of the Weka packages. I basically compiled it using the "javac -classpath CLASSPATH:weka.jar program_name.java" command, and everything was fine.

When I ran it using "java -Xmx2024m -classpath CLASSPATH:weka.jar program_name", the program threw a "NoClassDefFound" error stating that the main class "program_name" could not be found!

This problem is really puzzling as the compilation worked, and the program_name.class file is present in the folder. The weka.jar is present as well.

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing a $ ( or % depending on OS ) from the front of the CLASSPATH declaration?

Comment: The directory where `program_name.class` was created needs to be in the classpath, for example `-classpath .:$CLASSPATH:weka.jar` if it's in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for getting back guys! The "$" throws an error. I tried what Java Devil suggested, but I still get the NoClassDefFound message. The program works fine when I run it with Eclipse (Windows). When I try running it from the terminal, I get this problem.

Comment: How about java -Xmx2024m -classpath %CLASSPATH%:.:<path_to>/weka.jar program_name.

Comment: I tried it, but I am still having the same problem Dave. To make my explanation a little bit more clear, I am having the Java program in the weka-3-7-9 directory (the weka.jar is in the same directory as well). I see the class file being created upon compilation, but I just don't understand why it fails to recognize the class file.

Comment: The fact that it's NoClassDefFoundError vs ClassNotFound suggests that you either have a problem that a required reference from the named class is missing (and hence the named class cannot be verified), or that the named class is improperly located in the directory structure (relative to it's package name).  Can also in some cases be due to compiling with one version of a JAR and running with a different version.

Comment: The programs are not in package. I have the program and the weka.jar in the same directory(/home/my-files/weka-3-7-9). I also got into /home/my-files/weka-3-7-9 when I compiled the program using javac -classpath CLASSPATH:weka.jar program_name.java. The compilation went through. However, running the program threw the error. I see the class file in the same directory, and there was an anonymous inner class. The code works fine when I use the Windows version of Eclipse.

Comment: Like I said, you may have compiled with one version of a JAR and be running with a different version.

Comment: Checked that too. I am using the same version of the jar for both of them. Any thoughts on starting this as a fresh task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 
`java -Xmx2024m -classpath %CLASSPATH%:.:<path_to>/weka.jar program_name`.

The program you are trying to be run ( including its package name ) must be navigable from the directory you are in.

So, if your program was com.dave.MyProgram and  you compiled it into /home/dave/bin, and the weka.jar file was in /tmp. then you would try

```
cd /home/dave/bin

java -Xmx2024m -classpath .:/tmp/weka.jar com.dave.MyProgram
```

this is creating a classpath containing the current directory and /tmp/weka.jar, and running the fully qualified name of your program.

If your program is not in a package the colland would be

```
java -Xmx2024m -classpath .:/tmp/weka.jar MyProgram
```

Comment: The program is not in a package. To make it easier, I compiled the program into /home/../folder/weka-3-7-9 (i.e.I was in the weka-3-7-9 directory when I compiled the program, and the class file showed up there). The weka.jar, and the class file are in the same directory basically. However, I still get the error.

Comment: Actually, I will try what you just said after I compile the program into a different directory. Please give me a moment.

Comment: If they are all in the same directory and the class is not in a package you need to make sure that "." is on your classpath. You may also have to use ";" rather than ":" to separate the items on your class path. The separator is different for windows and Unix machines. If the program and the jar file are in the same directory, and your program is not in a package, and you have cd'd to that directory then you command would be java -Xmx2024m -classpath . MyProgram

Comment: Many thanks Dave! It finally worked when I tested it with another smaller program. I got that file not found error because my program tried to read from a file that I had renamed (and I forgot to change it in the program), and the memory allocation really depended on my program. I deleted those comments as they popped because I did something dumb. Anyway, thanks so much again for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling and running providing the path, rather then using the CLASSPATH

like so

`javac -cp .:(path)/weka.jar program_name.java`

replacing path with the path to weka.jar (unless it is in the same path as where you are compiling from, then just put .:weka.jar)

Also make sure you are loading/importing the classes you need into your program, for example

`Class.forName("what.ever.the.weka.class.you.are.using.is");`

Comment: Thank you for getting back! I tried it, but I still get the error. The program works fine when I use Eclipse. Is it alright if I use the import statements instead of Class.forName("...")?